# AppEngine JDO with multiple server instances loses transaction updates on entities fetched by key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have a simple JDO test cases that consistently reproduces the problem:
1. two app engine tasks modify the same entity at about the same time 
2. the tasks use a JDO transaction and use getObjectById to load the entity
3. have task A modify attribute A on the entity (assume A runs first)
4. have task B modify attribute B on the entity

The problem arises when each of the two tasks executes on two different app engine instances. In which case, I can see log messages that say task A has properly set attribute A to a non-null value and the transaction committed successfully. Then when task B runs on a separate instance it prints out that it does not see the changes that were made to attribute A by task A. Then task B logs that it has set attribute B to a non-null value and that its transaction completes successfully.

Then, when I look in the datastore, attribute A is still null even though I can see log output that says it was set to non-null and the transaction was successful. I would have expected one of two things: 1) when task B loads the entity the value of attribute A reflects that it has been set to a non-null value, or 2) task B loads stale data, but the commit fails with a "too much contention" error. Either of those would be fine. (Note that occasionally I do see contention errors)

What am I missing? It seems like there's some weird caching going on each instance. I was pretty sure that loading an entity by its key within a transaction should reflect changes made to that entity even when those changes are made on a separate app engine instance. When writing a test case to reproduce this I created completely new entity classes and tasks to ensure no other code was somehow mucking things up and I reproduced it in production (the devserver gives slightly different behavior).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are having a version issue. Use @version this will automatically handle concurrent modification and will throw an optimistic lock exception.

Comment: I think you're right. I was working under the mis-guided assumption that App Engine's datastore had some guarantees about loading the most recent values for an entity when you get the object by key within a transaction. I think it still might if I was using their low-level API or maybe Objectify. Is it possible this is a complication that is a symptom of using JDO?

Comment: Google's plugin for JDO (not JDO itself, which is simply a set of interfaces etc) logs what is sent to the datastore, so you can easily enough check what is being called in the lowlevel API (which is what every persistence library calls for that datastore).